# Use git to secure web project directories

Tags: git, security, content-management-system

I am working on a cms project set up on a very insecure server with numerous other projects out of my control.

Recently JS files have been placed, replaced and edited adding malicious code by unknown attackers through unknown vector. - The hoster refused to see the problem or help finding the loophole.
The customer refused to change the hoster or upgrade to a full blown root server which I could harden myself.(*sigh*)
To secure my project I thought of making publicly accessible directories git monitored so I could be notified of changes via a hook and repair the whole thing with a simple reset.

Question: Is there a reason I should not do this? Might this open up new security issues I don't see now?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use such servers. If somebody can change files on your file system, he might also change the configuration of your web- or application server or executables like git. If your system is corrupted in such a way, you cannot even trust the output of git.

In general git can check the integrity of your repository (see `git fsck`). Furthermore it can show you the differences between your working directory and the index (see `git status`). But their are some pitfalls: An attacker can create a local commits. In this case `fsck` passes and the output of `git status` is empty. Hence you have to verify that you still have the same ref.

If you have ignored directories or files a atttacker might use them to inject his code in your application. For example web frameworks like ruby on rails have their own `tmp` directory and use it to cache responses. This directory is normally ignored and hence git doesn't care if somebody manipulates these files.

Depending on your webservers configuration a simple `git clone your_repo` in your webroot might publish the content of your `.git` directory. In this case you have published your source and your complete history (a clone of a repository contains the whole history including author names and email addresses).

Ofcourse you shouldn't give the user write permissions on the repository you cloned from. Otherwise an Attacker might push his local commits to your repository. It might be hard to detect such commits, because he might use email addresses, name and commit messages from the history. This can be avoided by using signed commits and checking them.

If you be aware of these pitfalls, then git assures the integrity of your source code as you would expect. But it doesn't monitor this state, it doesn't actively tell you if something changed. If you checkout something and go away, git doesn't prevent somebody else from changing the files. You can only come back and see the changes and maybe revert them.